# What is topologically the set of all straight lines in $\mathbb{R}^d$? More structures on it?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

If we consider the set of all straight lines in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then what is it topologically? If it's topologically 'nice' i.e. a manifold, probably we could put a smooth manifold structure on it too. Can we put a Riemannian manifold structure?

For the first question, I'd think of it as a disjoint union over the points $p$ of all lines passing through a fixed point $p$. So I'm thinking it's something like $\mathbb{RP}^{d-1}\times \mathbb{R}^d$. But is it? If it is, I guess the other questions might be answered from it.

Comment: You can see it probably as the grassmannian $G(2,\mathbf R^{d+1}$, which is an algebraic variety.

Comment: If you look one dimension up, then all lines can become lines through the origin ($a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3=b$ becomes $ax_1+ax_2+ax_3=bx_0$), so it's just a projective space one dimension up.  The problem with your description is that if you have two points, $p$ and $q$ the line between them $l$ shows up at each point (i.e., $(l,p)$ and $(l,q)$ in $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{d-1}\times\mathbb{R}^d$).

Comment: @Michael Burr: could you explain the embedding in a little more detail? How can a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which doesn't pass through the origin can do so if you think of $\mathbb{R}^2$sitting in $\mathbb{R}^3$. And as Bernard answered, where exactly are we thinking of the two dimensional planes in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$. I do think you've a point, but a little more explanation would help me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Let $L^n$ denote the set of lines in $\mathbb R^n$. It's not the disjoint union over $p$ of lines passing through $p$, because for $p\ne q$, the sets $\{\text{lines passing through $p$}\}$ and $\{\text{lines passing through $q$}\}$ intersect. It's also not equal to the Grassmannian $G(2,\mathbb R^{d+1})$, because it's not compact.

One way to topologize $L^n$ is as a vector bundle over $\mathbb R\mathbb P^{n-1}$. The fiber over each line $[x]\in \mathbb R\mathbb P^{n-1}$ is the set of all lines parallel to $[x]$, which obtains a vector space structure by viewing it as the quotient space $\mathbb R^n/\operatorname{span}(x)$. The projection maps each line $\ell$ in $\mathbb R^n$ to the unique line parallel to $\ell$ and passing through the origin.

It obtains a smooth structure as a homogeneous space: the [affine group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) $\mathbb R^n \rtimes \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ acts transitively on $L^n$, with closed isotropy group $\mathbb R^{n-1}\rtimes \operatorname{GL}(n-1,\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 1):

As requested by the OP, here are more details.  Consider a line $l$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  This line is given by $ax+by=c$.  If $c\not=0$, then the line does not pass through the origin.  Now, consider the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $ax+by=cz$.  If you look at a slice of this plane at $z=1$, you are left with the line that you started with.  Moreover, the plane $ax+by=cz$ is unique and uniquely determines the original line.

If you consider the normal vector to this plane, you have a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that determines the plane constructed above.  The set of lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$.

The problem with this construction is that when $a$ and $b$ are zero, but $c$ is nonzero, such a plane does not correspond to a line.  Therefore, the space that you're looking for is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$.